# Understanding Docker on different platforms

Tags: docker, powerpc

If I have a docker image (Ubuntu image that runs my service) that I created on my Linux machine (x86), will that run on Linux on PowerPC without any issues? Or will I have to rebuild the docker image on Linux on PowerPC. I am a bit confused about the cross platform/architecture support w.r.t. Docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [this thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/5eptm9/are_docker_containers_cross_platform_or_no/) : **no**, the images are not cross-platform. Although the thread is pretty old - I don't believe anything has changed in this matter.